# React Form field formatting errors

Tags: reactjs

My input field collapse when I try to enter any data I think the field class is changing with on change function. Like the form control class is not holding at the time of entering data.I am new with creating and developing things using react js.I am using atom as the editor. I hope someone is going to find the problem.

```
      render() {
        const errors = validate(this.state.companyname, this.state.intro,this.state.aboutus,this.state.service,this.state.address,this.state.instruction);
        const isDisabled = Object.keys(errors).some(x => errors[x]);
        return (
          <div>
          <div>
          <b>Webgen</b>
          </div>
          <div class="App">
          <ul class="progress-indicator">
  <li class="completed"> <span class="bubble"></span> Step 1. </li>
  <li class="completed"> <span class="bubble"></span> Step 2. </li>
  <li> <span class="bubble"></span> Step 3. </li>
  <li> <span class="bubble"></span> Step 4. </li>
</ul>
<p>Step 2</p>
          <header>
          <h1>About Website</h1>
        </header>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input
              className={errors.companyname ? "error" : "" }
              type="text"
              placeholder="Your Comapny Name/Business Name"
              value={this.state.companyname}
              onChange={this.handlecompanynameChange}
              class="form-control"
            /><br/></div>
             <div class="col-md-2"><button class="btn btn-primary">Upload Logo</button></div></div>
            <input
              className={errors.intro ? "error" : ""}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Company Business Intro"
              value={this.state.intro}
              onChange={this.handleintroChange}
              class="form-control"
            /><br/>
            <input
              className={errors.aboutus ? "error" : ""}
              type="text"
              placeholder="About Us Text"
              value={this.state.aboutus}
              onChange={this.handleaboutusChange}
              class="form-control"
            /><br/>
            <input
              className={errors.service ? "error" : ""}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Your Service Product"
              value={this.state.service}
              onChange={this.handleserviceChange}
              class="form-control"
            /><br/>
            <input
              className={errors.address ? "error" : ""}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Your Address"
              value={this.state.address}
              onChange={this.handleaddressChange}
              class="form-control"
            /><br/>
            <input
              className={errors.instruction ? "error" : ""}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Adittional Instruction"
              value={this.state.instruction}
              onChange={this.handleinstructionChange}
            /><br/>
            <Link to="/mokeup3" ><button class="btn btn-primary" disabled={isDisabled}>Sign up</button></Link>
          </form>
          </div>
          <div>
        <footer>
        <b>Website Wizard</b>
        </footer>
        </div>
        </div>
        )
      }
    }
export default mokeup2;
```

Comment: show us onchange functions, also what do you mean by input field collapse? do you get any errors? or things just don't work as you expect?

Comment: do you have your repo public?

Comment: I just got the problem solved....Thank u for consideration...!! @Geoman